# Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin not found

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-powershell

I created new `config` file for Kubernetes from `Azure` in `Powershell` by `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <RGName> --name <ClusterName>`. Got a message that `Merged "cluster_name" as current context in C:\michu\.kube\config`. I copied this file into default `.kube\config` location and now when I try to run any command e.g `kubectl get pods` I am receiving:

```
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
```

What is wrong here?

I just realized that when I type `kubectl config get-contexts` then I can see my `cluster_name` and I can even switch to this by `kubectl config use-context cluster_name` and message is correct: `Switched to context cluster_name` but then still all other commands ends with `Unable to connect to the server: getting credentilas: exec: executable kubelogin not found`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error implies that the `kubelogin` executable could not be located. You need to install `kubelogin` in the azure cli using
`az aks install-cli`, then it works as expected.

Refer [github](https://azure.github.io/kubelogin/install.html) for installation process.

*I tried the same requirement in my environment, and it worked for me as follows.*

```bash
az aks get-credentials --resource-group caroline --name sampleaks1
kubectl get pods
```

***Output:***

[image]

Once you have the `aks` credentials, running `kubectl get pods` will prompt you for an `Azure kubernetes service authentication with AAD`, as shown.

[image]

*Just give* `kubectl` *in the bash* *to verify whether it is installed successfully.*

[image]

*If still the issue persists,*

1. Delete all the cache or any unused folders inside the ~/.kube/ and ran the aks credentials command by adding
   `--admin` flag in the end.

   Refer this [doc](https://blog.baeke.info/2021/06/03/a-quick-look-at-azure-kubelogin/) by @Geert Baeke for more related information.
2. Check the kube config version and upgrade if required.

Comment: why we never had this issue before? Is it caused by breaking changes introduced by az command?

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways and in the end what solved it was to install 'kubelogin'
https://azure.github.io/kubelogin/install.html
https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/6586#issuecomment-1325973051

And add "--admin" as @Jahnavi said.

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group my-rg-prd --name my-cluster-prd --admin.
```

This Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the following `az aks install-cli`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1106601/aks-access-issue